# string to enum value in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have my enum defined like this.

```
 public enum Places : long
  {
    World = (long)1,
    India = (long)23424848,
    USA = (long)23424977
  }
```

Now I get a string of value like 'India'. I want the corresponding value of the enumerator.

for instance if i get the string 'World'(or world - case insensitive ), I need the value 1 to be returned.

I tried this way:

```
long woeid = ((long)(typeof(Places)country));
```

this doesnot work.

Is there a simple way to do?

Comment: I dont think you want to use an enumerable here, Try possibly using a dictionary with the location as the Key and the long as the Value

Comment: This is how it is designed. I have to work with this

Answer (score 3):

The method you want is [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx).

You would use it like this:

```
string country = "India";
Places myplace = (Places)Enum.Parse(typeof(Places), country);
long placeID = (long)Enum.Parse(typeof(Places), country);
```

Comment: I still get the value as India. I need the value which is '23424848'

Comment: Is there a way to take rid of case-sensitiveness. The string India and india should return 23424848. The string World and world should return 1 ?

Comment: I assume you missed the minor update I made to get a long out as well as the enum which should give you the number. As for the case-sensitivity I assume by now you've actually followed the link to the overloads of enum.parse so you could see the one that deals with case sensitivity?